# JMeter does not record nor execute javascript code, the "buttons" will not be rendered in JMeter

Tags: javascript, ajax, jmeter, load-testing, outsystems

I am working on performance testing using jmeter for my application

I am able to successfully record a test plan. Each http request to server has got `__OSVSTATE` & `viewstate` attribute value in request.

While navigating from one page to another I am able to extract this attribute from page using Regular expression extractor and used it in the new subsequent request.

I have some pages in my applications which sends ajax requests multiple times, for each response of request a new `__OSVSTATE` attribute value is getting generated and sent in the `<script> </script>` tag `json` format and it seems this value gets used in the new request.

Can someone give me suggestions to achieve this in `JMeter`?

Each record inside container has html button using which user clicks accept button.

In JMeter I am recording this whole process, after successful recording when I start script again in the JMeter - result tree shows response only in json format and not in HTML view like other pages.
I am able to execute http request there is one request- `'/PerformanceProbe/rest/BeaconInternal/WebScreenClientExecutedEvent'` which internally gets execute and fails.
Do you know reason behind this or if you have any other suggestions or solutions please share here.

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways of creating scripts in Jmeter for web applications. Firstly, you can create selenium scripts in jmeter using "JMeter's WebDriver Sampler" which will launch browser, perform different actions. Secondly, you can use the HTTP sampler which will record network requests. i.e. it will not display browser and work on the request/response level. For now, you are using the second method and that is the reason you are unable to see HTML.

The first method is not recommended for high user load because it consumes a lot of memory.

Regarding failure of the network requests, you need to make sure that all the parameters and headers are properly used.